# Adding custom .less file to bootstrap: error during compiling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a .less file to be compiled with the rest of the .less bootstrap files. I use Less app on OSX.
My file is called style.less (yes i know, very original!!!!).
In the bootstrap.less i added the following at the end: @import "style.less";

So everything is working well when compiling. But if i use some variables in my style.less file, i get an error during compiling saying that my variable is not defined in style.less

But i do the same in an existing .less file that comes with bootstrap, i don't get that error.

Am i missing something?

thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention, the variable that i am trying to use in style.less file are existing variables from other bootstrap .less files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the code from the style.less file. It may contain very small syntax mistake in it.

Try to add classes one by one. In my case if I write + operator as ( @ten-pixel+3 ) still it gives error so correct syntax is ( @ten-pixel + 3 ) .

Hope it gives some clue.

Answer (score 0):

that was the part flagged during compiling from my newly added file style.less :

```
#top {
height: 150px;
font-size: @smallFontSize; // check how to set this in variable.less
border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
margin: ;
}
```

i was getting an error saying that @smallFontSize was undefined. If i add the following at the top of my style.less file to define the variable such as:

```
@smallFontSize: 11px;
```

then no error are showing during compiling.

ps: @smallFontSize is from the file called variable.less

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are importing style.less after you are trying to use the variable?